# unable establish remote imap connection, why not?

Tags: centos, email, imap, dovecot, firewalld

A remote CentOS 7 web server is able to successfully receive email sent from elsewhere on the internet addressed to me@mydomain.com .  An app running on the same CentOS 7 server is able to use JavaMail to make an IMAP connection to the dovecot Maildir where the incoming messages get stored.  **So what do I have to add in order for  Thunderbird running on my devbox to be able to make an IMAP connection to the remote CentOS 7 server across the internet?**

So far, I added `imaps` to the public zone of firewalld.  I also confirmed that dovecot.conf contains the line `protocols = imap pop3`.  I configure Thunderbird to use IMAP for incoming mail, with mydomain.com as the hostname, with port 993 and SSL with normal password.  And I confirmed at my domain registrar's web site that the dns mx entry uses mydomain.com as the mx address.

**EDIT**

To answer @Celada's question, I have posted the dialog that Thunderbird gives indicating that it has failed to connect to the server when it tries to confirm my login information.  I get the same information when I specify port 993 for imap and port 25 for smtp, and when I indicate SSL connection.  Also, changing .mydomain.com to mydomain.com does not eliminate the login failure.

[image]

I will try to access the firewalld logs next and will post results.  My understanding is that firewalld does not log automatically, so I will have to develop some rich rules.  It might take some time to identify the proper syntax.

**I think it is a server config problem.  I hesitated to show the Thunderbird dialog because I did not want to give the impression that it is a client issue.  I think the server config needs to be determined/set-up before I can set up Thunderbird.**

**EDIT#2**

As per @Celada's suggestion, I typed `telnet localhost 143` and got the following response:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS LOGINDISABLED] Dovecot ready.
```

I also typed `telnet localhost 25` and then got the following in response:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix
```

These telnet results pointed out that firewalld was mapping imaps and smtp to the wrong ports, so I typed `nano /usr/lib/firewalld/services/imaps.xml` and changed the port from 993 to 143.  And then I typed `nano /usr/lib/firewalld/services/smtp.xml` and changed the port to 25.

I then typed `firewall-cmd --reload` to ensure that the changes were put into effect.

Next, I put the new information into Thunderbird and tried a test connection again, but again got a failure message shown by the following dialog box:

[image]

Note that I checked the MX record in the DNS at my domain registrar, and it is exactly `mydomain.com`, as shown in the screen shots.  I don't see how this is irrelevant.  I did check and the hostname on the server is also `mydomain.com`.  Is there some other resource I should be checking to confirm the correct mail server name instead?

Also note that dovecot and postfix were installed with a standard configuration.  I did not explicitly configure ssl to work with them, though SSL may have been part of the default configuration.  I did, however, change the settings in the dialog box above and tested a connection with **None** specified in the SSL field, but got the same failure message.

The dovecot log in /var/log/maillog after the most recent (bottom) screen shot above is:

```
Feb 27 00:52:57 mydomain dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=my.DEVBOX.ip.addr, lip=my.SERVER.ip.addr, session=<YsH2egsQAABi9AyF>
```

**EDIT#3**

Following @Bandrami's advice, I changed `protocols = imap pop3` in dovecot.conf to `protocols = imaps pops`.  I then made sure that `/usr/lib/firewalld/services/imaps.xml` specifies port 993.  I typed `firewall-cmd --reload` and `systemctl stop dovecot` then `systemctl start dovecot` to restart the relevant processes on the server.  I then configured the Thunderbird test to specify port 993 and SSL/TLS and re-ran the connection test in Thunderbird, only to get the same result in Thunderbird.

The dovecot logs, however, are a little more explicit, and are as follows:

```
Feb 27 01:18:20 mydomain dovecot: config: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf
Feb 27 01:18:20 mydomain dovecot: config: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:26: 'imaps' protocol can no longer be specified (use protocols=imap). to disable n$
Feb 27 01:18:38 mydomain dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 18 secs): user=<>, rip=my.SERVER.ip.addr, lip=127.0.0.1, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:14$
Feb 27 01:19:15 mydomain dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Feb 27 01:19:15 mydomain dovecot: anvil: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Feb 27 01:19:15 mydomain dovecot: ssl-params: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Feb 27 01:19:15 mydomain dovecot: config: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Feb 27 01:19:15 mydomain dovecot: auth: Error: read(anvil-auth-penalty) failed: EOF
Feb 27 01:19:15 mydomain dovecot: auth: Error: net_connect_unix(anvil-auth-penalty) failed: Permission denied
Feb 27 01:19:15 mydomain dovecot: auth: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Feb 27 01:19:15 mydomain dovecot: log: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Feb 27 01:19:22 mydomain dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.10 starting up for pop3, imap (core dumps disabled)
Feb 27 01:19:44 mydomain dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 15 secs): user=<>, rip=my.SERVER.ip.addr, lip=127.0.0.1, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:14$
Feb 27 01:23:55 mydomain postfix/qmgr[30121]: 2C915811BD1C: from=<me@mydomain.com>, size=5316, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 27 01:23:58 mydomain postfix/smtp[27144]: 2C915811BD1C: to=<address@domain_that_sends_to_this_addresson_server.com>, relay=none, delay=290245, delays=290241/0.02/3.6/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain$
Feb 27 01:24:41 mydomain dovecot: config: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf
Feb 27 01:24:41 mydomain dovecot: config: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:26: 'imaps' protocol can no longer be specified (use protocols=imap). to disable n$
Feb 27 01:24:41 mydomain dovecot: config: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf
Feb 27 01:24:41 mydomain dovecot: config: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:26: 'imaps' protocol can no longer be specified (use protocols=imap). to disable n$
Feb 27 01:24:53 mydomain dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 12 secs): user=<>, rip=my.SERVER.ip.addr, lip=127.0.0.1, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:14$
Feb 27 01:25:05 mydomain dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 1 secs): user=<>, rip=my.DEVBOX.ip.addr, lip=my.SERVER.ip.addr, TLS, session=<Kdrl7QsQxwBi9AyF>
Feb 27 01:27:16 mydomain dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Feb 27 01:27:16 mydomain dovecot: anvil: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Feb 27 01:27:16 mydomain dovecot: log: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Feb 27 01:27:24 mydomain dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.10 starting up for pop3, imap (core dumps disabled)
Feb 27 01:27:24 mydomain dovecot: config: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf
Feb 27 01:27:24 mydomain dovecot: config: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:26: 'imaps' protocol can no longer be specified (use protocols=imap). to disable n$
```

**EDIT#4**

As per @Celada's further clarification, I typed `telnet imap.mydomain.com 143`, in the local devbox that I've been using for Thunderbird testing, and the terminal replied with:

```
Trying my.SERVER.ip.addr...
Connected to imap.mydomain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS LOGINDISABLED] Dovecot ready.
```

Next, I typed in `openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs -starttls imap -port 143 -host imap.mydomain.com` at the devbox terminal, and the terminal replied by printing out [the details which you can read by clicking on this link to a file sharing site](https://jumpshare.com/v/gocgDoGSD9eMcFh2kl50?b=A7FkBPrR24o36dforeU2).

My complete [dovecot.conf can be read at a file sharing site by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/Qdw7gAr3X91vqTnRsJoO?b=MJLqD0V8Qx7l6T8jdIAx).

**EDIT#5**

As per @Celada's suggestion, I typed `t1 login USERNAME PASSWORD` after `. OK Pre-login capabilities listed, post-login capabilities have more.`, and the terminal replied with the following:

```
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT MULTIAPPEND URL-PARTIAL CATENATE UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS SPECIAL-USE BINARY MOVE
t1 OK Logged in
```

However, I then repeated the Thunderbird login test, and I checked to force Thunderbird to use port 143 and "Normal password".  When I did this, Thunderbird forced "Autodetect" as the SSL option, and then clicking the "Re-test" button resulted in the same error message:

```
"Thunderbird failed to find the settings for your email account."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some back-and-forth through comments and chat the OP's problem is now resolved. The IMAP server needed to be specified as **imap.mydomain.com** instead of **mydomain.com** although for some reason this only worked when set using the advanced account settings, not using the account creation dialog box.

In addition to mentioning this situation-specific solution, I think that the most useful thing I can say in an answer to this question is to list some generic troubleshooting tips on the topic in the hopes that they will be useful to someone else reading this later.

- Thunderbird's feature to autodetect account settings is fantastic and a great improvement over the dark days of email account setup when ISPs had to provide long-winded instructions including everything from the server type (POP or IMAP) through the port numbers to the authentication protocol. In an ideal world users would only need to specify their email address, password, and maybe I guess the server name (that's all they need for accessing gmail through the web, after all...).

  Yet when the autodetection feature doesn't work, you get almost nothing in the way of useful error messages. "Thunderbird failed to find the settings for your email account" means basically nothing.

  TIP: when Thunderbird's autodetection feature isn't working, don't waste time on it, and fall back to specifying everything manually until it works. Then, once you have it working, you can concentrate of finding out why autodetection failed and maybe fixing it so it will work for the next user.
- Always use port 143 for IMAP if you can. There is also port 993 for IMAP over SSL, but all reasonably modern clients and servers support STARTTLS for upgrading unencrypted connections to encrypted ones, so there really isn't any need anymore to worry about different ports for IMAP. Connections on port 143 will automatically be encrypted if possible.
- (Not related to IMAP but anyway) Always use port 587 for SMTP if you can. SMTP used to always be done on port 25, but ISPs frequently block port 25 because of spam. Port 587 was designated specifically for SMTP communication between MUAs and mail servers, is expected to support SMTP AUTH and STARTTLS as necessary, and has already been in existence for many years. There is rarely any need to worry about configuring MUAs to use any other port.
- Dovecot treats unencrypted connections and encrypted connections differently, and this may also apply to local connections (to `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or `::1`) versus remote connections. The most common types of authentications are insecure over unencrypted remote connections, so Dovecot does not offer them.

  Therefore, when testing and debugging through the command line, in order to simulate a real MUA most closely, test remotely and use STARTTLS to encrypt connections. Otherwise you may find that authentication works fine with `telnet` and still wonder why it doesn't work on the MUA.
- Test using `telnet` (for unencrypted connections) or `openssl s_client` (for encrypted connections)

  Use the same hostname that you are trying to get the MUA to accept. If you want `imap.mydomain.com` or `mail.mydomain.com` or just `mydomain.com` to work when specified as the mail server in the MUA, test using the same host name from the command line. And if you get a hostname resolution error, you know that the problem lies in DNS.

  ```
  openssl s_client -starttls imap -port 143 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs -host <hostname>
  ```
- If the SSL certificate configured on the Dovecot server has a problem, Thunderbird will warn about that but it will still allow you to connect. If you are completely unable to connect, the certificate is probably not the problem.

  Of course, once you are ready to go in production, you will want to use a certificate signed by a recognized certificate authority and have the name on the certificate match the IMAP server name that gets configured in MUAs.
- Useful IMAP commands for testing. Type these into IMAP sessions you open with `telnet` (unencrypted) or `openssl s_client` (encrypted)

  ```
  tag1 LOGOUT
  tag2 LOGIN <username> <password>
  tag3 CAPABILITIES
  tag4 LIST "" "*"
  ```